# Can a wlan router also receive wlan?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a linksys wrt router and i was wondering if it can also be used to not only setup a wifi network but also connect to existing ones and share the connection via its lan ports?

Comment: If you have a 2nd router you can set up a wireless bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, it's known as **wireless bridging**. Depending on your model it's most easily achievable using 3rd party firmware such as DD-WRT or Tomato, the latter being preferred if your router is compatible.

See here:

http://tomatousb.org/doc:build-types

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database

Comment: I wouldn't say one is preferable to the other. They both have pros and cons and are both far more powerful than default home router firmware. It mostly comes down to preference.

Comment: It's subjective, but in terms of fitting the purpose of the user asking the question most would agree it's simpler to set-up things like bridging with Tomato's very intuitive interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you're trying to say is that you want to use your router as a wireless receiver. This site might help: http://www.techerator.com/2009/09/how-to-use-a-router-as-a-wireless-adapter/

If you want to strengthen your wifi coverage by resharing (bridging) the signal by another router look up router bridging.